# Service with MediaPlayer Force Closes

Tags: android

I have a Service with a MediaPlayer which streams audio from the Internet but when I press the Home button and it goes back to the home screen it Force Closes. It's strange though because it works perfectly in the emulator and sometimes it doesn't Force Close on my phone (G1), when I've just turned it on. 
This is my code:

```
    public class backgroundPlayer extends Service {

 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {

 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  MyMainClass.myMediaPlayer.stop();
 }

 @Override
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
  MyMainClass.myMediaPlayer.reset();

  try {  MyMainClass.myMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MyMainClass.channelUrl[player.selectedChannel]);
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  try {
   MyMainClass.myMediaPlayer.prepare();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  MyMainClass.myMediaPlayer.start();
 }
}
```

Log:

```
08-01 02:51:29.467: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Start proc com.android.settings for broadcast com.android.settings/.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider: pid=17820 uid=1000 gids={3003, 1015, 3002, 3001}
08-01 02:51:29.467: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/.Launcher }
08-01 02:51:29.547: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Start proc android.process.acore for activity com.android.launcher/.Launcher: pid=17823 uid=10003 gids={1015, 3003}
08-01 02:51:30.287: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Process com.google.android.voicesearch (pid 17726) has died.
08-01 02:51:30.306: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-01 02:51:30.427: INFO/ActivityThread(17823): Publishing provider com.android.launcher.settings: com.android.launcher.LauncherProvider
08-01 02:51:30.457: INFO/ActivityThread(17823): Publishing provider user_dictionary: com.android.providers.userdictionary.UserDictionaryProvider
08-01 02:51:30.497: INFO/ActivityThread(17823): Publishing provider com.android.social: com.android.providers.contacts.SocialProvider
08-01 02:51:30.537: INFO/ActivityThread(17823): Publishing provider applications: com.android.providers.applications.ApplicationsProvider
08-01 02:51:30.757: INFO/ActivityThread(17823): Publishing provider contacts;com.android.contacts: com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2
08-01 02:51:31.457: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Process com.android.settings (pid 17820) has died.
08-01 02:51:31.467: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-01 02:51:31.667: DEBUG/dalvikvm(17823): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2871 objects / 200896 bytes in 116ms
08-01 02:51:31.687: INFO/ActivityThread(17823): Publishing provider call_log: com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider
08-01 02:51:31.957: DEBUG/dalvikvm(17823): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 967 objects / 49736 bytes in 110ms
08-01 02:51:33.867: DEBUG/dalvikvm(17823): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 6359 objects / 416536 bytes in 154ms
08-01 02:51:34.666: DEBUG/dalvikvm(17823): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1253 objects / 75368 bytes in 306ms
08-01 02:51:35.297: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Displayed activity com.android.launcher/.Launcher: 83778 ms (total 5806 ms)
08-01 02:51:37.347: DEBUG/HomeLoaders(17823):   ----> items cloned, ready to refresh UI
08-01 02:51:38.237: DEBUG/Launcher(17823): about to setAppWidget for id=6, info=AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{com.android.deskclock/com.android.alarmclock.AnalogAppWidgetProvider})
08-01 02:51:38.417: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Start proc com.android.deskclock for broadcast com.android.deskclock/com.android.alarmclock.AnalogAppWidgetProvider: pid=17862 uid=10011 gids={}
08-01 02:51:38.817: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Process com.ktix007.mira (pid 17708) has died.
08-01 02:51:38.817: INFO/WindowManager(123): WIN DEATH: Window{4407fd70 com.ktix007.mira/com.ktix007.mira.Mira paused=false}
08-01 02:51:38.827: WARN/ActivityManager(123): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.ktix007.mira/.bgPlayer in 5000ms
08-01 02:51:38.847: WARN/TimedEventQueue(96): Event 315 was not found in the queue, already cancelled?
08-01 02:51:38.857: INFO/WindowManager(123): WIN DEATH: Window{440a3ed0 com.ktix007.mira/com.ktix007.mira.player paused=false}
08-01 02:51:38.867: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-01 02:51:38.907: INFO/ActivityThread(17862): Publishing provider com.android.deskclock: com.android.deskclock.AlarmProvider
08-01 02:51:39.717: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Process com.android.deskclock (pid 17862) has died.
08-01 02:51:39.727: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-01 02:51:39.907: DEBUG/dalvikvm(17823): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7394 objects / 409864 bytes in 140ms
08-01 02:51:40.197: DEBUG/Launcher(17823): about to setAppWidget for id=2, info=AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.SearchWidgetProvider})
08-01 02:51:40.247: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Start proc com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox for broadcast com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/.SearchWidgetProvider: pid=17869 uid=10044 gids={3003}
08-01 02:51:41.017: INFO/ActivityThread(17869): Publishing provider com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.google: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.google.GoogleSuggestionProvider
08-01 02:51:41.627: DEBUG/Launcher(17823): about to setAppWidget for id=7, info=AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider})
08-01 02:51:41.667: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Start proc com.android.settings for broadcast com.android.settings/.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider: pid=17878 uid=1000 gids={3003, 1015, 3002, 3001}
08-01 02:51:42.747: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Process com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox (pid 17869) has died.
08-01 02:51:42.757: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-01 02:51:43.067: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Process com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget (pid 17590) has died.
08-01 02:51:43.077: WARN/ActivityManager(123): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget/.GenieRefreshService in 10750ms
08-01 02:51:43.097: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-01 02:51:43.397: DEBUG/dalvikvm(17823): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8354 objects / 423984 bytes in 409ms
08-01 02:51:43.567: DEBUG/Launcher(17823): about to setAppWidget for id=8, info=AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget/com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget.miniwidget.MiniWidgetProvider})
08-01 02:51:43.667: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Start proc com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget for broadcast com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget/.miniwidget.MiniWidgetProvider: pid=17887 uid=10048 gids={3003, 1015}
08-01 02:51:43.887: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Start proc com.ktix007.mira for service com.ktix007.mira/.bgPlayer: pid=17892 uid=10053 gids={3003}
08-01 02:51:44.576: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(17892): Shutting down VM
08-01 02:51:44.576: WARN/dalvikvm(17892): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207e8)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.ktix007.mira.bgPlayer@43c9e050 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3063)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at com.ktix007.mira.bgPlayer.onStart(bgPlayer.java:35)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
08-01 02:51:44.677: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17892):     ... 10 more
08-01 02:51:45.137: DEBUG/Launcher(17823): about to setAppWidget for id=10, info=AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{com.android.music/com.android.music.MediaAppWidgetProvider})
08-01 02:51:45.197: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Process com.android.settings (pid 17878) has died.
08-01 02:51:45.197: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-01 02:51:45.267: INFO/ActivityThread(17887): Publishing provider com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget.weather: com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget.providers.WeatherProvider
08-01 02:51:45.417: INFO/ActivityThread(17887): Publishing provider com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget.newsimage: com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget.providers.NewsImageProvider
08-01 02:51:46.197: WARN/Genie(17887): Cache file not found: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget/files/genie_iconcache (No such file or directory)
08-01 02:51:46.487: DEBUG/Launcher(17823): about to setAppWidget for id=11, info=AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.youtube/com.google.android.youtube.widget.WidgetProvider})
08-01 02:51:46.896: DEBUG/dalvikvm(17887): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9118 objects / 346184 bytes in 247ms
08-01 02:51:47.437: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Start proc com.android.music for broadcast com.android.music/.MediaAppWidgetProvider: pid=17907 uid=10020 gids={3003, 1015}
08-01 02:51:47.517: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Process com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget (pid 17887) has died.
08-01 02:51:47.517: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-01 02:51:48.137: INFO/dalvikvm(17823): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
08-01 02:51:48.277: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Start proc com.google.android.youtube for broadcast com.google.android.youtube/.widget.WidgetProvider: pid=17914 uid=10023 gids={3003}
08-01 02:51:48.587: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Process com.android.music (pid 17907) has died.
08-01 02:51:48.587: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Low Memory: No more background processes.
08-01 02:51:48.647: INFO/ActivityThread(17914): Publishing provider com.google.android.youtube.SuggestionProvider: com.google.android.youtube.suggest.SuggestionProvider
08-01 02:51:49.027: INFO/YouTube(17914): Distribution channel:mvapp-android-google
08-01 02:51:49.827: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Process com.google.android.youtube (pid 17914) has died.
08-01 02:51:49.827: INFO/ActivityManager(123): Low Memory: No more background processes.
```

Comment: What is the `adb logcat` output for the force close? It'll probably have a stack trace.

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: Can you please give feedback for the answers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert but I'll try to offer an answer since I've been working with this same sort of thing.

Ok see if any of this helps:

1) Get rid of `onStart()` I don't even think that's used anymore?

2) Put all the code you have in `onStart()` into `onCreate()`. Don't forget `super.onCreate();` as the first line of the `onCreate()` method.

3) As the first line of the `onDestroy()` method you need `super.onDestroy();`

4) Also do a `MediaPlayer.release();` in your `onDestroy()` method after you stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Android releases all static variables when low on memory. It makes the static variables null.
That's probably the source of the NPE (NullPointerException).